# Submit button not accepting css styling

Tags: css, button

I have a submit button in a form that isn't taking on all the style I have set for it. I want the submit button to look the same as a "next section button I have, but it looks different

Here's some relevant HTML:

```
<form>
    <a href="#step2" class="btn">Next Section >></a><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Application" id="submit" />
</form>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.btn, #submit {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius:6px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: poiner;
    float: right;
}
.btn:hover, #submit:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #777;
}
```

And here's a JS Fiddle which shows the output differences: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSwJN/4/)

Comment: Looks the same to me (Chromium 24/Ubuntu 12.10), except for the width (which isn't defined in your CSS).

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/hSwJN/14/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this CSS on the submit button.

```
#submit {
    border: none;
}
```